# Can't get github hosting to work with Jekyll 3.0.0

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I am new to both Jekyll and github. I have followed the instructions [here](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/usage/jekyll-quick-start.html) to get a blog on github using Jekyll. When I type `jekyll serve` from my local directory I get

```
D:/projects/gitblog/MyName.github.com/jekyll-bootstrap/_plugins/debug.rb:13:in `<module:Jekyll>': cannot load such file -- jekyll/post (LoadError)
```

Can someone help me with this? Based on some thing I have read, this might be a problem with the latest version of Jekyll, which I am using,

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the file `_plugins/debug.rb` and run the server again.